# HD video conferencing and HD screen sharing at an acceptable frame rate

Tags: screen-recording, video-conferencing, screen-sharing

I've checked out the free trials of [WebEx](http://www.webex.com/), [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/), and [ClickMeeting](http://www.clickmeeting.com/), and they work wonderfully for webcams – however I'm finding that they're all similar in that they lock screen captures to very low FPS (typically less than 15). I know the hardware of all devices involved is more than capable of going higher than this, and I have tried these software packages with several different powerful computers to make sure that is the case.

In short, and as a little background info: My company's CEO is looking for a high-quality remote collaboration all around solution (or at least 30fps when he or someone else in the call shares their screens!). He is willing to pay quite a bit for it as well. I simply can't find anything that works without layering software tools on top of each other. We've even discussed the possibility of using something like GTM *in addition to* a software like OBS, Xsplit, etc. – and while that's an option, we want to keep this task as simple as we possibly can.

As for the platform, we are flexible. We use mostly Windows but also have Macs and iOS devices as well. So we can flex around if we find something that works.

Thank you all for your help with this.

Comment: The biggest question and the reason that the frame rate of most is capped is not the computers it is the available network bandwidth.  What is the connection like?

Comment: @SteveBarnes We've got a fiber line run in, but each port (and Wifi connection) is throttled at 40mb symmetrical.

Comment: How about at the other end + in between? That is likely to be the problem area - unless you are only doing in house conferencing.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Some of the conferences will span the globe (as in Europe, Israel, and the US) but from what I've been told, most of the use will come in-house.

Answer (score 1):

We use MS Lync (or Skype for business). It has the following functions:

- Screen sharing (25 - 30 fps. Don't really know, but it looks fine)
- Video conferences
- The Other party can even take control over the screen if wanted
- Integration with MS Exchange (For planning meetings)
- The other party can participate in the meeting through a web app if the don't use lync
- Offers chat functionality (So you can use it for internal team communication)

There is a free version, but for companies you need licenses it. But I don't know how the licensing work but I assume it is not cheap

Answer (score 0):

Try Facewebinar - www,facewebinar.com

Its a web based Video conferencing tool with following features and sets up the meeting in less than 10 seconds.

Audio Web Based call
Video 
Screen Sharing

Comment: Does this handle >= 30 fps?